# Optimizing MySQL query that uses temp table and lots of joins

Tags: mysql, sql, centos

I have below query:

```
SELECT id, title, organisation, logo, body, state, state_name, state_order, closing_date, end_date, state_abbr, GROUP_CONCAT(portfolio_id SEPARATOR ',') portfolios, organisation_type_id, featured, hide_apply_link, hide_company_title,description
                FROM(
                    SELECT * FROM(
                        SELECT 
                            j.id, 
                            j.title, 
                            CONCAT(o.name,IF(j.organisation_department = '','',CONCAT(' - ',j.organisation_department))) organisation,
                            o.id organisation_id, 
                            o.logo logo,
                            j.body body,
                            j.plain_body plain_body,
                            IF(d.is_state = 1, s.name,d.name) state, 
                            d.name state_name,
                            d.order state_order,
                            IF(j.hide_closing_date = 1, 'N/A', DATE_FORMAT(j.end_date,'%d %b')) closing_date,
                            j.end_date end_date, 
                            j.created newest, 
                            pjc.category_id category, 
                            d.state_id sid, 
                            s.name state_abbr, 
                            p.id postcode,
                            pj.port_id portfolio_id,
                            o.organisation_type_id,
                            j.featured,
                            j.hide_apply_link,
                            j.hide_company_title,
                            o.description
                        FROM
                            commstratjobs.portfolio_job_category pjc,
                            commstratjobs.organisation o,
                            commstratjobs.display_category d,
                            commstratjobs.section_job sj,
                            commstratjobs.state s,
                            commstratjobs.portfolio_job pj,
                            commstratjobs.job j
                        LEFT JOIN  commstratjobs.postcode p ON p.id = j.postcode_id
                        WHERE pjc.job_id = j.id AND  j.id = sj.job_id AND
                                    sj.section_id = d.id AND
                                    j.organisation_id = o.id AND
                                    s.id = d.state_id AND
                                    pj.job_id = j.id AND
                                    j.published = 1 AND
                                    DATE(j.start_date) <= CURRENT_DATE AND
                                    DATE(j.end_date) >= CURRENT_DATE


                                    ) all_jobs  WHERE state_abbr = 'ACT' GROUP BY id, portfolio_id) all_jobs_grp GROUP BY id ORDER BY featured DESC, end_date ASC;
```

I have indexes set up for each id and joining ids

The problem is that I'm getting above 10 seconds for each of above query.

Is there a way to optimize above?

Below is output of `EXPLAIN` statement:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: PRIMARY
        table: <derived2>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 21
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 2
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: <derived3>
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2700
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: pjc
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 24
          ref: NULL
         rows: 181535
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: j
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,organisation_id
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: commstratjobs.pjc.job_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: o
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: commstratjobs.j.organisation_id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: p
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: commstratjobs.j.postcode_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: pj
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 8
          ref: commstratjobs.j.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where; Using index
*************************** 8. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: d
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
        Extra: Using join buffer
*************************** 9. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: s
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 1
          ref: commstratjobs.d.state_id
         rows: 1
        Extra:
*************************** 10. row ***************************
           id: 3
  select_type: DERIVED
        table: sj
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 9
          ref: commstratjobs.pjc.job_id,commstratjobs.d.id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using index
10 rows in set (1.05 sec)
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a view for your SELECT statement in the inner brackets. I think mysql recompiles the statement for each run. If you have a view it may optimise it once and for all. Just try to create a view see if it makes difference. On the side note, you can easily move WHERE state_abbr = 'ACT' inside the first bracketed SQL statement, as well as all the GROUP BY clauses, reducing the number of nested dynamic views

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Comment: As Andy Lester mentioned we need to see table definitions and maybe index deifnitions as well. HOwever the most important part is the output of the explain statement. Could you please put that in your question.

Comment: Comment: `DATE(j.start_date) <= CURRENT_DATE AND DATE(j.end_date) >= CURRENT_DATE` should be rewriten without the use of `DATE()` function if you want any index on `start_date` or `end_date` to be used.

Comment: Comment2: The 3-level nesting is not at all needed. The internal `all_jobs` derived table can be rewritten without nesting. If the other nesting can be also removed, it would help, too.